# Object slicing, vector element out of scope

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store a derived class in a vector without object slicing. I've
been looking hard for most of the day and haven't figured out how to make it work.
Solutions I've read about suggest storing pointers to the derived objects instead
of the actual objects. I couldn't get that to work, but I want to add these objects
to a vector in such a way which will result in the objects going out of scope before
the vector goes out of scope. So, I don't think that kind of solution will work
anyway. Another solution suggests making the base class abstract but that didn't
work either. I read about overriding the assignment operator and the copy
constructor but I don't think they ended up doing anything different from the normal
assignment operator and the noraml copy constructor. I tried that with a virtual
assignment operator too with no success. Below is an example of what I have been
working with. The "vec.emplace_back(&derivedEvent);" statement in the main method
results in the base class being added to the vector. Immediately afterward, the
object goes out of scope and the vector no longer contains derivedEvent's data. I'm
still quite new to programming so anything I tried may have been done incorrectly.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CBaseEvent {
protected:
    CBaseEvent(){}
    std::string m_strBeginning;
    std::string m_strEnd;
public:
    CBaseEvent(std::string strBeginning, std::string strEnd)
    : m_strBeginning(strBeginning), m_strEnd(strEnd){}
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CDerivedEvent : public CBaseEvent {
private:
    CDerivedEvent(){}
    std::string m_strMiddle;
public:
    CDerivedEvent(
        std::string strBeginning,
        std::string strMiddle,
        std::string strEnd)
        : CBaseEvent(strBeginning, strEnd),
        m_strMiddle(strMiddle){}
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CBaseEvent>> vec;
    if (true) {
        CDerivedEvent derivedEvent = CDerivedEvent("1", "2", "3");
        vec.emplace_back(&derivedEvent);
    }
    return 0; //CRASH: possible corruption of the heap
}
```

Comment: `I want to add these objects to a vector in such a way which will result in the objects going out of scope before the vector goes out of scope` doesn't make any sense. If you want to erase an element from a vector, use `std::vector::erase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the object in the stack and inside the scope of the if statement, once it goes out of that scope the object will no longer exist, and when the share_ptr is destroyed by the vector going out of the scope of the main function your program will crash since it will attempt to destroy an object that no longer exists.

this:

```
 if (true) {
        CDerivedEvent derivedEvent = CDerivedEvent("1", "2", "3");
        vec.emplace_back(&derivedEvent);
    }
```

Should be:

```
 if (true) {
        CDerivedEvent* derivedEvent = new CDerivedEvent("1", "2", "3");
        vec.emplace_back(derivedEvent);
    }
```

It should work as you expect, but as Jhon Purdy said in the comment below, this would be more appropiate:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CBaseEvent> > vec;

    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<CBaseEvent>(new CDerivedEvent("1", "2", "3")));

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use `vector<`[`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)`<CBaseEvent>>` to manage the element lifetimes.

Comment: Yes, vector<unique_ptr<CBa‌​seEvent>> would be more appropiate, since there is only one reference to the CBaseEvent object.

Comment: Not sure what you gain by emplacing, rather than simply pushing back, a pointer.

Comment: I just corrected the part of his code that was making it crash, didnt modify the rest of it.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CBaseEvent>>` is the right approach, but for filling it in the best way will (in C++14) be `vec.push_back(std::make_unique<CDerivedEvent>(whatever))`.  Definitely pass a `std::unique_ptr` to the vector, and don't rely on `emplace_back` to create the `unique_ptr`, because if reallocation is necessary and fails, `emplace_back` wouldn't construct the `unique_ptr` and wouldn't free the `CDerivedEvent` object.

Comment: Also, and I can't emphasize this enough, the technique shown in this answer **requires CBaseEvent to have a virtual destructor**

Comment: Thank you all very much for taking the time to help me. I made some changes according to your input and was able to get it to work by using dynamic_cast. First, I added a virtual destructor to CBaseEvent. Then I used "vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<CBaseEvent>(new CDerivedEvent("1", "2", "3")));" From there I used "dynamic_cast<CDerivedEvent*>(vec[0].get())->" to access the CDerivedEvent. This was a huge help and I'm very excited to have this working. Should CDerivedEvent have a virtual destructor too? Also, how do I highlight the code portions of my comment instead of using quotes?

Comment: For code, use the backtick ````.  `CDerivedEvent` will have a virtual destructor if any of its base classes do.

Answer (score 1):

I like the

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CBaseEvent> > vec;
```

approach used by AngelCastillo a whole lot, but there's just one thing wrong with it.

`std::unique_ptr<CBaseEvent>(new CDerivedEvent(blah))` will result in deleting an object of type `CDerivedEvent` via pointer of type `CBaseEvent*`.  Since `CBaseEvent` doesn't have a virtual destructor (it is not even polymorphic), this is undefined behavior.

This can be fixed by either

- adding a virtual destructor
  or
- using `std::shared_ptr`, which preserves the type information internally inside the deleter.

  ```
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CBaseEvent> > vec;
  vec.push_back(std::make_shared<CDerivedEvent>(whatever));
  ```

Comment: Excellent answer. It's a shame C++11 left in that whole with `std::make_unique` inviting all kinds of old-fashioned confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was very helpful. I made a virtual destructor as you suggested. I was able to access the CDerivedEvent stored in the vector after using dynamic_cast.